# Kickstart exception occurred

Tags: centos

My centos 6.6 kickstart fails with a "exception occurred" message and references users.py amungst others.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

I thought it maybe related to root password but I have changed that to something simpler as a test but it still does it.

[image]

The bottom half of the error message

[image]

Comment: Can you get the exact exception? Does it have something to do with not finding a user (talks about a `lookupUserByName` or `setpassUser` function)? Have you looked at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda to see about getting more information about of anaconda about what is failing?

Comment: Added screen capture

Comment: What media are you using to install CentOS? Specifically what version(s) of the `nss-softokn*` packages does the media contain?

Comment: I'm installing from an ISO i build with revisor pulling packages from the centos repo's nss-softokn-3.14.3-22.el6_6.i686.rpm

Comment: Assuming that version matches for the `nss-softokn` and `nss-softokn-freebl` pacakges I would like to believe the problem I was thinking about it gone but I haven't tested it again since the `-19` version broke it and I reverted to the `-18` version. If you can control things so as to revert to the `-18` version of those two packages I would suggest trying that and seeing if that works.

Comment: Yes the nss-softokn and nss-softokn-freebl packages match but nss is nss-3.16.2.3-3.el6_i686.rpm perhaps I need to adjust where I'm pulling my packages from

Comment: No. I think that's the right version of that package... at least assuming you meant `nss-3.16.2.3-3.el6_6.i686.rpm`.

Comment: Yes I do. So you are suggesting rolling back a version to help resolve the issue? What do we think the issue is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73435/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-user3246938).

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1187089

Comment: Yes. I believe (though I can't see the linked bug) that that is the issue I am talking about. Hopefully that means they know about it and can fix it. Did you get a chance to try the older version of the `nss-softokn` packages?

Comment: I'll see if I can trick revisor into using an older package. I'm sure I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I exclude the update repository from my revisor build I get an ISO which actually installs properly. So it looks like there is a broken package in the updates repo.

nss-softtoken in the update is at version 22 but in the OS repo it's ate 17. Although I can't say for sure at this point if it is the nss-softtoken it now on an earlier version.

Getting closer

Comment: It was nss-softtoken. It's fixed in later verions